# JavaScript Regular Expression to get a url value

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a Regular Expression which can meet my request below:

1. It can get characters between 'id=' and '&'
2. the character '&' may exist or not

here's a example, say I have two URL like below:

1. http://example.com?id=222&haha=555
2. http://example.com?id=222

The Regular Expression can get the key *id*'s value *222* in both URL.

VERY THANKFUL if someone can help me solve this problem!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex to get the id value whether it is followed by a `&` symbol or line end `$`.

```
id=(.*?)(?=&|$)
```

The captured value was stored inside the  group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zI7xF3/1)

```
> var re = /id=(.*?)(?=&|$)/g;
undefined
> var str = 'http://example.com?id=222&haha=555';
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
...     console.log(m[1]);
... }
222
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the regexp way but this should also work

```
str.split("id=")[1].split('&')[0]
```